# Magento 2 - Update all configurable products after migration

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, price

I have migrated all the Magento 1.9.2 products to Magento 2.2.4 and would need that in each configurable product a single price is applied to each SKU, the price that the configurable product has.

Now all the configurable products are using the price attribute to each Sku.

Would there be a way to make an update of all the configurable products and for all of them to use a single price be applied to each SKU?